# Right argument to setAlpha?

Tags: android, colors, alpha

In Android, the setAlpha function used to set the transparency is accepting different arguements in different classes. In `View` or any of its derived classes setAlpha accepts `float` as the argument (0 being completely transparent and 1 being completely opaque). In `Drawable` and its derivative setAlpha accepts int as the argument (0 being completely transparent and 255 being completely opaque).

Is this any solid reason why there is this difference in argument between the Classes over the same property?

Comment: as I know old versions of android pre ICS Views used int 0 - 255 for alpha, and after that they used alpha 0-1, maybe there was no updates on Drawable class since that, or there was no need.

Answer (score 3):

`setAlpha` on `Drawable` was around before `setAlpha` on `View..`
`Drawable.setAlpha(0-255)` was more efficient method of setting the alpha as the resulting alpha is that byte value.. so it was more direct, and float's were expensive. Now with hardware rendering float's are better as this value directly correlates to the the GPU feature.

Credit: Napalm

Comment: Ok, I get that. But shouldn't they kept it alike, as in when they changed it in View to float the same change should have been done for Drawable as well right? It kinda looks wierd to see setAlpha accepting different types as argument in such a popular OS.

Comment: really I don't have any idea, but seem they didn't update Drawable till now.